# Rails e postgres group_by por data considerando time zone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, active-record

Como eu faço para agrupar registros por data onde o campo é do tipo datetime? Porém isso considerando o timezone.

Por exemplo:

Quando o usuário digitar 12/10/2014 23:30:00, é gravado no banco 13/10/2014 01:30:00, pois o nosso fuzo horário é -2:00 atualmente.

Meus dados em banco:

```
|Descrição | created_at           |
|Reg 1     |  10/10/2014 17:00:00 |
|Reg 2     |  11/10/2014 01:30:00 | <-- Gostaria que fosse considerado como o dia 10/10/2014
|Reg 3     |  09/10/2014 05:30:00 |
```

Quando eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
Movimento.select("date(created_at) as dia, count(*) as qtd").group("dia")
-> [Movimento({:dia => '09/10/2014', :qtd => 1 }), Movimento({:dia => '10/10/2014', :qtd => 1 }), Movimento({:dia => '11/10/2014', :qtd => 1 }) ]

Eu gostaria que o resultado fosse:
-> [Movimento({:dia => '09/10/2014', :qtd => 1 }), Movimento({:dia => '10/10/2014', :qtd => 2 })]
```

Como eu faço para que seja considerado o timezone no meu select e group_by?

Comment: Sua aplicação é utilizado em várias timezones diferentes? Se não, a forma mais simples é alterar a timezone que o rails incluie no banco. Veja essa [resposta do SOen](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7701732/2099835).

Comment: Sim, eu preciso que seja utilizado com várias timezones diferentes, pois temos alguns clientes que estão em outros países.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provavelmente seu banco está com o timezone 'UTC', se você quer pegar o fuso horário dinamicamente conforme está configurado no [ruby-on-rails](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails), utilize o seguinte:

```
Movimento.select("date(created_at AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE '#{Time.zone.tzinfo.name}') as dia, count(*) as qtd").group("dia")
```

Answer (score 1):

Para o horário de verão use `BRST`.

```
select(
    "date(created_at at time zone 'UTC' at time zone 'BRST') as dia, count(*) as qtd"
).group("dia")
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, porém não posso utilizar o BRST  pois senão sempre irá 2 horas, e caso não esteja no horário de verão, preciso que seja diminuído 3 horas.

Comment: @Bruno: Foi metade da resposta, não foi? O Anderson colocou a parte to Rails.

Comment: Sim, porém como o Anderson colocou o Time.zone.tzinfo.name, ao invés de pegar o BRST irá pegar America/Sao_Paulo, e com isso o postgres sabe quando a data é horário de verão (-2 horas) e quando é horário normal (-3 horas). Da maneira como você colocou irá sempre setar -2 horas.